# Empty screen for data retrieval

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from `firebase` to a `listview`...However this code returns a blank screen .My database has a child **Dog Expenditure** with two nodes on it

- Amount
- Item

I have tried all methods i know i just get an empty screen. Someone please help me out here

All i see is an empty screen.

I have no idea on how to solve this anyone please:

**The code is here**

```
package com.example.moses.farm;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Mystatement extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference dref;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mystatement);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        dref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        dref= dref.child("Dog Expenditure").child("amount").child("item");
        dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                list.add(value);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


            }
        });
    }
}
```

My activity is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_mystatement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.moses.farm.Mystatement">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your activity_mystatement.xml file?

Comment: sure @Farid i have edited my question with it.

Comment: @Farid anything??

Answer (score 0):

You say you have a node "Dog Expenditure" with two nodes (amount and item) inside of it.

When you do `dref= dref.child("Dog Expenditure").child("amount").child("item");`
You're trying to find an item node inside of an amount node inside of a Dog Expenditure node. If you're trying to get both amount and child, you should just be using `dref.child("Dog Expenditure")` and get the amount and item from the datasnapshot value.

### Edit

If all you're trying to do is load all Dog Expenditures from the Database you could use this.

```
dref= dref.child("Dog Expenditure");
dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                HashMap<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String, Object>) child.getValue();
                String amount = (String) value.get("amount");
                String item = (String) value.get("item");
                // This will print out amount and item
                System.out.println(amount + item);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: i just need to at least see one value or anything for that matter then i can now move on from there..Currently no result in anyhing..

Comment: help me get at least anything from the database.

Comment: Post some JSON from your firebase database

Comment: Dog Expenditure
 ---KeT_eEhkkiKJYOo1hb5
          -- amount: "12'000"
          --item: "gsgag"

Comment: i get this error too com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

Comment: Yeah, give me a sec, I'll edit my answer with the code you need

Comment: hey Error  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap lol

Comment: @ PieterLaebens this errors thou. just ran into another 1

Comment: These are fairly simple errors and you should be able to fix these yourself. If you're getting a String cannot be cast to HashMap error though then your database doesn't look like you described it. Or you changed something in my code.

Comment: sorry man. i am new to android and java in general..the thing is, i still have a blank page...WHY..if there is no error then its a blank page,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137278/discussion-between-pieter-laebens-and-sir-george).